# how to add and remove select box options if other select box options changes to the same options in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, angular2-template

**My Requirement**

I need to remove the options which exist in another select box, when the same option is selected in another select box

**What I have done**

I have created 3 select boxes and loaded with the same values in it, and I have created a 2 functions `enableAllOptions` `disableOptions`, in `enableAllOptions` functions am enabling all the options for the first time and in `disableOptions` am disabling the options based on the options selected from select box

I'm pasting the fully functional [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8rZyS06ByBfH4IOIVo2T?p=preview) for your reference (there is a issue in data loading in the select box)

this is my HTML CODE

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div class="container">
        <form role="form" calss="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label>Select State:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rules.State" id="sel1">
 <option *ngFor="#hey of states" value="{{hey.value}}">{{hey.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label>Rule:</label>
<input type="text" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label>Pass State :</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rules.pass">
 <option *ngFor="#hey_pass of state_pass" value="{{hey_pass.value}}">{{hey_pass.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label>Fail State:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rules.fail">
 <option *ngFor="#hey_fail of state_fail" value="{{hey_fail.value}}">{{hey_fail.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Rules Configuration</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Rules</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

The `app.component.ts` file in the plunkr link please have a view, this may be duplicated question but this question is based on Angular 2.0 not AngularJS 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of (change) event as:

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rules.State" id="sel1" (change)="statechange($event.target.value)">
 <option *ngFor="#hey of states" value="{{hey.value}}">{{hey.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

And in .ts file define a method "statechange" and remove the value from states array.

Comment: not working have created a function called updateDisabled and detected the change using ngModelChange, the code is available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139567/trying-to-disable-the-selected-options-from-select-box-if-it-is-selected-in-anot

Comment: if you are able to get the selected value in .ts file using either (change) or (ngModelChange) then you can use the value to disable the option.

Comment: actually the disabling part is a big mess I have used angular 1.x its uses ng-disabled but in angular 2.x it uses like this [disabled], did you tried the above code

Comment: bro can you please see the above link which I mentioned in the comment and see whether you can coorect that code because its working fine in angular 1.x

Answer (score 0):

Slightly changed the logic. Instead of one state list I am using 3, each for each select dropdown with name and disabled property for each state. Pls see the sample code to disable the option:

states = [{ name: "state1", disabled: false }, { name: "state2", disabled: false }, { name: "state3", disabled: false }, { name: "state4", disabled: false }];

states1 = [{ name: "state1", disabled: false }, { name: "state2", disabled: false }, { name: "state3", disabled: false }, { name: "state4", disabled: false }];

states2 = [{ name: "state1", disabled: false }, { name: "state2", disabled: false }, { name: "state3", disabled: false }, { name: "state4", disabled: false }];

statechange(curState: string) { for (var i = 0; i < this.states.length; i++) {

```
        if (this.states1[i].name == curState) {

            this.states1[i].disabled = true;
            this.states2[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

}